# Как ловить mouse events для группы SVG форм, как единого целого?

Tags: raphael, javascript, события

Разбираюсь с [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com) и SVG. Есть графический объект, состоящий из нескольких: напр., окружность и внутри неё квадрат поменьше.

Как ловить мышиные события  для этой пары, будто она одно целое?

Пробовал:

1. вешать `onmouseover` на бОльший (окружность): когда курсор заходит на квадрат, происходит `onmouseout` окружности;
   Встречал «решение» рисовать поверх группы почти прозрачную форму, покрывающую всю активную область, и вешать слушателя на неё. Как-то «неаккуратненько»..
2. делать из них [`set`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set), и цеплять Raphael'овский [`mouseover( handler)`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.mouseover) на этот сет: срабатывает для каждого из объектов сета.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант -  отлавливать `mouseenter` и `mouseleave` для группы элементов (`<svg:g />`).  Raphael в "базовой поставке" это не поддерживает  (set не является группой), но есть расширения которые позволяют добавить в него возможность работы с группами, вот например это `https://github.com/rhyolight/Raphael-Plugins`.

А дальше просто - берём группу и вешаем на неё `mouseenter` - `mouseleave`. Вот что-то [типа этого](http://jsfiddle.net/dMyyA/).

Comment: Круто, не знал, что `set != g`, думал, они одно и то же. Спасибо большое за лаконичный ответ идеально в тему.

Answer (score 2):

В SVG можно делать группы: <g></g>

На них можно вешать евенты.

Comment: Можно, см. п.2 в вопросе. Пробовал создавать set'ы: когда мышка едет извне на сначала внешнюю форму, затем внутреннюю, происходят события: внешний.mouseover, внешний.mouseout, внутр.mouseover: как если бы слушались события на каждом из составляющих объектов. Т.е. они НЕ являются единым целым.

Upd. точно, вы правы. Я ошибочно полагал, что в Raphael set это именно svg:g. Ответ @mantigatos прояснил этот момент.